# How to pass a variable to app in Zendesk

Tags: javascript, json, zendesk

I'm experimenting with Zendesk apps but I'm having an issue passing variables / an array of json objects from my app into the view. I did the getting started tutorials and looked at the API but I can't seem to find an answer.

Here is what I have:

```
this.ajax('fetchExternalData', myURL).done(function(data) {
    this.switchTo('requester', data);
});
```

but whenever I try to access data in the app, it says it's undefined (data is an array of objects here).

```
I even tried something like:
    this.ajax('fetchExternalData', myURL).done(function(x) {
        this.switchTo('requester', x);
    });
```

Where x is just some plain text.

if I do:

```
this.ajax('fetchExternalData', myURL).done(function(data) {
    data = data[0];
    this.switchTo('requester', data);
});
```

I can access properties in data by their name (eg. {{CustomerName}}) but I still can't reference the data var itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [Zendesk site](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/introduction) :

```
this.switchTo('hello', {username: currentUser});
```

> The first argument specifies the template to render, hello, which references the hello.hdbs file in the templates folder. The second argument specifies the data to pass to the template, ***expressed as a JavaScript object literal***, {username: currentUser}. The current user's name is passed to the template to be displayed in the user interface.

So just try like that :

```
this.ajax('fetchExternalData', myURL).done(function(data) {
    //this.switchTo('requester', data);
    this.switchTo('requester', {data : data} );
});
```

I hope this will resolve your issue !